# HTTP authentication not working with CGI enabled

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

I'm using the HTTP authentication using the example #2 provided in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/features.http-auth#example-374).
I've successfully configured the script and now I can login through HTTP using my defined credentials. But if in my MAMP I switch the mode from `Identical PHP version for all hosts (module)` to `Individual PHP version for every host (CGI)` the script will ask me for a correct username and password infinitely even if the username and password are correct.

[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Found this, maby it helps? http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html

Comment: I faced similar issue while ago and it turned to be with regard to the header's key naming. in CGI mode i couldn't use **Authorization** to send my token, since on the server side it would be empty. my workaround was to change the key name to **CGIAuthorization**. however this only worked because i had access to both server and client side and could make the change.

Comment: As @sanderbee mentioned there are some [good mod_rewrite workaround](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20cgi%20http%20authentication&es_th=1) which worth a try

Answer (score 0):

After reading dozens of pages about this issue, I concluded that there is no workaround for using CGI with the HTTP Digest authentication.

However, there is a workaround if your are able to use the HTTP basic authentication. So I implemented an exception in case the Server API is running CGI and preserved my Digest Authentication in case the server is running Apache Module.

I've followed the [link](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html) provided by @sanderbee.
This [link](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/HTTP-Digest-authentication-does-not-work-with-PHP-as-CGi-td4658790.html) also helped me.

Using the predefined constant [PHP_SAPI](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-os) I've managed to check if the Server API is running CGI, and if it's true, I run the basic HTTP authentication:

```
function admin_digest_auth(){
    if (substr(PHP_SAPI, 0, 3) == 'cgi') {
        return admin_basic_auth();
    }

    // You HTTP Digest authentication code ...
}

function admin_basic_auth(){
    // split the user/pass parts
    if(isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTH']) && !empty($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTH'])){
        list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = 
            explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTH'], 6)));
    }

    // open a user/pass prompt
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

        exit('Unauthorized');

    // validate submited user / pass
    } else {
        if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] !== 'admin' ||
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] !== 'mypassword'){
            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
            admin_basic_auth();
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

And to conclude, you have to add this line in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTH:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```